# custom keybaord as default (Disable AOSP Keyboard)

Tags: java, android, android-custom-keyboard

I want to develop my own on-screen keyboard for Android.
This keyboard should be the only selectable keyboard on the Android device.

I was able to create the keyboard, but something is still missing. I can't disable the AOSP keyboard. This is possible with some keyboards from other developers, such as SwiftKey

Take a look at my screenshots to understand my problem

Custom keyboard **can't** disable AOSP Keyboard:
[image]
SwiftKey **can** disable AOSP Keyboard:
[image]

You can use the following github project to create your own keyboard with the problem
https://github.com/alanszlosek/android-keyboard

I already tried to support multiple languages `en_US` and `de_DE`, but without success

Which conditions have to be fulfilled so that my APP can be the only selectable on-screen keyboard under Android?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have your app as the only selectable on-screen keyboard. I guess you might need to ask for system administrator privileges for this, which many users would be reluctant to give.

Comment: @pri
I do not think that's the case
The SwiftKey keyboard was installed with an APK-File.

SwiftKey has no system rights, but can disable the AOSP keyboard